# Update WMS Layer's Time Property with a TimeSlider Widget in ArcGIS JavaScript 4 SDK

Tags: wms, arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, timeslider

Using the ArcGIS JavaScript 4 SDK/API to load the WMS service of a NOAA Coast Watch Sea Surface Temperature dataset. The dataset that is trying to be loaded is an aggregated dataset which should contain the daily data for the entire year of 2022. See [here](https://www.star.nesdis.noaa.gov/thredds/catalog/socd/coastwatch/catalog_coastwatch_sst_blended_ghrsst_ospo_aggregated.html) in the online file server for the years available. Clicking through to the WMS server reveals the WMS get capabilities request in the browser; this details the dates on which the data is contained. The goal is to create something like [this](https://coastwatch.noaa.gov/cw_html/cwViewer.html?lat=27.00&lon=-80.80&z=3&date=20231015&layer0=basemapWI&layer1=ghrsstBlendedOSPOd) but natively in ArcGIS JS SDK. View the full codepen [here](https://codepen.io/mendesd/pen/ZEVNdmE/).

The WMS layer is loaded by the below code:

```
// SST (aggregated)
    const layer2 = new WMSLayer({
        url: "https://www.star.nesdis.noaa.gov/thredds/wms/BlendedSST5kmNightAggGHRSSTOSPO2022?service=WMS&version=1.3.0&request=GetCapabilities",
        sublayers: [{ name: "analysed_sst" }],
        customParameters: {
            STYLES: 'boxfill/Rainbow',
            COLORSCALERANGE: '271,310',
            FORMAT: 'image/png',
            NUMCOLORBANDS: 215
        },
        timeExtent: {
            start: new Date(Date.UTC(2022, 0, 2))
        },
        useViewTime: false
    });

    const map = new Map({
        basemap: new Basemap({ // "dark-gray-vector" // Basemap layer service. OG -> arcgis-topographic
            portalItem: {
                id: "1a386c5dfd864bfda3f03ab428e57640"  // dark-gray-vector WGS84 
            }
        })
    });

    const view = new MapView({
        map: map,
        container: "viewDiv", // Div element
        center: [-75.056, 38.540], // Longitude, latitude
        zoom: 5 // Zoom level
    });
```

The map's time extent is not set explicitly, so the `useViewTime` is set to false.

I tried using a watch function to monitor and update the `timeExtent` property of the WMS layer. However, the `timeExtent` of the WMS layer is not set before it is called in the watch function (hence the commented out `console.log()` statement. The watch statement and time slider initialization is below:

```
const timeSlider = new TimeSlider({
        container: "TimeSliderDiv",
        // show data within a given time range
        // in this case data within one year
        mode: "instant",
        fullTimeExtent: { // entire extent of the timeSlider
            start: new Date(Date.UTC(2022, 0, 2)),
            end: new Date(Date.UTC(2022, 11, 31))
        },
        timeExtent: { // location of timeSlider thumbs
            start: new Date(Date.UTC(2022, 0, 2))
        },
        stops: {
            interval: {
                value: 1,
                unit: "days"
            }
        }
    });
    view.ui.add(timeSlider, "bottom");
    
    timeSlider.watch("timeExtent", (time) => {
        console.log("Time extent now starts at", time.start, "and finishes at:", time.end);
        // console.log(layer2.timeExtent.start,layer2.timeExtent.end);
        layer2.timeExtent = time;
        console.log(layer2.timeExtent.start,layer2.timeExtent.end);
        
    });
    

    map.add(layer2);
});
```

Removing any part of the time extent from either place they are at now did not fix my problem.

How do I get the time slider to update the WMS layer's time component and ensure that the date in the time slider is correct for the data being pulled?

One last thing I tried from researching the WMS from Thredds Server [here](https://docs.unidata.ucar.edu/tds/current/userguide/index.html) that then takes me to [here](https://www.ogc.org/standard/wms/). With the downloaded enchodin scheme about the time variable I tried to implement the below with no luck chaning the time property.

```
 const layer = new WMSLayer({
        url: "https://www.star.nesdis.noaa.gov/thredds/wms/BlendedSST5kmNightAggGHRSSTOSPO2022?service=WMS&version=1.3.0&request=GetCapabilities",
        sublayers: [{ name: "analysed_sst" }],
        customParameters: {
            STYLES: 'boxfill/Rainbow',
            COLORSCALERANGE: '271,310',
            FORMAT: 'image/png',
            NUMCOLORBANDS: 215,
            TIME: "2022-01-01T12:00:00.000Z"
        },
        // fullTimeExtent: { // entire extent of the timeSlider
        //     start: new Date(Date.UTC(2022, 0, 2)),
        //     end: new Date(Date.UTC(2022, 11, 31))
        // },
        // timeExtent: {
        //     start: new Date(Date.UTC(2022, 0, 2)),
        //     end: new Date(Date.UTC(2022, 0, 2))
        // },
        useViewTime: true
    });
```

Even changing `TIME: "2022-01-01T12:00:00.000Z"` to `DIMENSION: "2022-01-01T12:00:00.000Z"` did not work.

Comment: hello, any luck with this? I also need to control WMS/WMTS with TIME dimension by passing the TIME parameter to the GetMap/GetTile Requess, is there a widget or some third party widget or some open source custom solution for this? thank you

Comment: @jurajmurcko not yet. Hopefully soon though. Still working on it.